# Label Range between two points on scatterplot with the percent difference

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

I have a simple scatterplot showing sales difference between years at different ranges.

So, when the range is ">$400", sales are X in 2013 and X in 2014.

I am trying to add an annotation at certain points showing the percent difference from 2013 to 2014.  Is that possible?

Here is the dput:

```
structure(list(Year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L), Range = structure(c(8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 26L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 23L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 26L), .Label = c("$40M", 
"$50M", "$60M", "$70M", "$71-80M", "$81-90M", "$91-100M", "$101-110M", 
"$111-120M", "$121-130M", "$131-140M", "$141-150M", "$151-160M", 
"$161-170M", "$171-180M", "$181-190M", "$191-200M", "$200-225M", 
"$226-250M", "$251-275M", "$276-300M", "$301-325M", "$326-350M", 
"$351-375M", "$376-400M", ">$400M"), class = "factor"), Avg_TOTALS = c(44732492.5, 
42902206, 47355762, 49604750.6666667, 51132411, 51943986, 54798652.5, 
61313778.5, 68577392, 74457422.6666667, 84805802.5, 96762417, 
99355792, 172956681, 189815908, 31762600.8571429, 33042576.2857143, 
34964083.8, 34349980.2, 35193407, 36049038.6666667, 42039793.3333333, 
486133671, 35996925, 35496337.5, 39139472.5, 36993568.5, 39570379, 
40139421.5, 43835119, 51358298.5, 53024160, 61185564, 67726723, 
71481251, 89873814, 27746650.1428571, 27633867, 29855703.5714286, 
29655265.2, 31163788.8, 29240507, 33810795.25, 192756973)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Range", "Avg_TOTALS"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-44L))
```

And here is the chart I am currently generating:

```
orderlist = c("$40M", "$50M", "$60M", "$70M", "$71-80M", "$81-90M", "$91-    100M", "$101-110M", "$111-120M", "$121-130M", 
              "$131-140M", "$141-150M", "$151-160M", "$161-170M", "$171-180M", "$181-190M", "$191-200M", "$200-225M",
              "$226-250M", "$251-275M", "$276-300M", "$301-325M", "$326-350M", "$351-375M", "$376-400M", ">$400M")

myDF = transform(myDF, Range = factor(Range, levels = orderlist))

myChart <- ggplot(myDF, aes(x = Range, y = Avg_TOTALS)) +
           geom_point(aes(color = factor(Year))) + 
           theme_tufte() +
           theme(axis.text.x= element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0)) +
           labs(x = "Range", y = "Sales by Range", title = "MyChart")+
           scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(50000000, 100000000, 200000000,
                                         300000000,400000000, 500000000),
                              labels = dollar)
```

Which gives me:

[image: MyChart]

And leads me to this question:

How would I add the percent difference between each of those points, with 2013 being the base year?  Also, there are a few ranges where there were sales in only one of the two years- would it be possible to skip the percent labels on those?  A condition in which data must exist in both years to be included?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. I think there are better ways. This is my best with my sleepy brain right now. Hope you do not mind that. Let me briefly explain the code. I followed you. Then, I obtained the data which ggplot is using, which I called foo. I created a master data frame to deal with missing data points and used join. The dplyr part was doing some calculation and stuff to get proportion. Using the outcome of it in `annotate`, I assigned the labels you wanted. Hope this will help you. zzz...

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(Year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L), Range = structure(c(8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 26L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 23L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 26L), .Label = c("$40M", 
"$50M", "$60M", "$70M", "$71-80M", "$81-90M", "$91-100M", "$101-110M", 
"$111-120M", "$121-130M", "$131-140M", "$141-150M", "$151-160M", 
"$161-170M", "$171-180M", "$181-190M", "$191-200M", "$200-225M", 
"$226-250M", "$251-275M", "$276-300M", "$301-325M", "$326-350M", 
"$351-375M", "$376-400M", ">$400M"), class = "factor"), Avg_TOTALS = c(44732492.5, 
42902206, 47355762, 49604750.6666667, 51132411, 51943986, 54798652.5, 
61313778.5, 68577392, 74457422.6666667, 84805802.5, 96762417, 
99355792, 172956681, 189815908, 31762600.8571429, 33042576.2857143, 
34964083.8, 34349980.2, 35193407, 36049038.6666667, 42039793.3333333, 
486133671, 35996925, 35496337.5, 39139472.5, 36993568.5, 39570379, 
40139421.5, 43835119, 51358298.5, 53024160, 61185564, 67726723, 
71481251, 89873814, 27746650.1428571, 27633867, 29855703.5714286, 
29655265.2, 31163788.8, 29240507, 33810795.25, 192756973)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Range", "Avg_TOTALS"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-44L))


orderlist = c("$40M", "$50M", "$60M", "$70M", "$71-80M", "$81-90M", "$91-    100M", "$101-110M", "$111-120M", "$121-130M", 
          "$131-140M", "$141-150M", "$151-160M", "$161-170M", "$171-180M", "$181-190M", "$191-200M", "$200-225M",
          "$226-250M", "$251-275M", "$276-300M", "$301-325M", "$326-350M", "$351-375M", "$376-400M", ">$400M")

mydf = transform(myDF, Range = factor(Range, levels = orderlist))

g <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x = Range, y = Avg_TOTALS)) +
     geom_point(aes(color = factor(Year))) + 
     #theme_tufte() +
     theme(axis.text.x= element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0))+
     labs(x="Range", y = "Sales by Range", title = "MyChart")+
     scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(50000000, 100000000, 200000000, 300000000,400000000, 500000000), labels = dollar)

library(dplyr)

foo <- ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]] %>%
       arrange(group) %>%
       mutate(year = c(rep("2013", times = 23), rep("2014", times = 21)))


master <- expand.grid(year = c("2013", "2014"), group = 1:24)

full_join(master, foo, by = c("year", c("group" = "x"))) %>%
group_by(group) %>%
mutate(prop = round(order_by(year, y / first(y)), 2)) %>%
summarise(y = first(y), prop = min(prop, na.rm = FALSE)) -> txt

g + annotate("text", x = txt$group, y = txt$y + 15000000, label = txt$prop)
```

[image]